# Flutter - http request with large response

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart, mobile

I have the following code:

```
  print("Start request");
  var response = await Dio().post(url, 
    data: FormData.fromMap({ 'Filters': '', 'OrderBy': '' }), 
    options: Options( 
        contentType: "multipart/form-data" , 
        headers: headers
      ),
    );
  print("Final");
  print("status code: " + response.statusCode.toString() );
  print("status code: " + response.data );
```

Very straight forward. If the response is small, everything works well. But, if the response is larger, the application blocks without any error on the  **await Dio().post** line.

This only happens on the real Android device ( I didn't test it on a real iOS device ). On the Android/iOS simulator it works well also.

Also, the same thing happens using the https darts module, not only with Dio.

Comment: where you are awaiting? Inside a widget? post the full code.

Comment: *"Also, the same thing happens using the https darts module, not only with Dio."* because, by default all on those packages try to keep your huge response in memory - probably you need to read it in stream mode, byte by byte

Comment: @pskink, I think the same, but I don't know how to get the response as stream.

Comment: read `dio` documentation on https://pub.dev/, btw how big is your response?

Comment: Not so big. This is the strange thing. It's a json for about 86KB.